# Someone sends a link to a product - 404 page

Tags: 404-page

If someone sends me a link of a product from my 1.9.3.9 webstore and I open it on my computer, I get a 404 page. When I refresh it, the product page appears correctly. URL stays the same before and after refresh. No URLs changed. What could be the problem?

Comment: Any errors in console after first load?

Comment: No, unfortunately not

Comment: Please check access.log and wriite error here